# Раскройка макета (вёрстка)

Tags: css

Хотелось бы узнать, как опытные верстальщики разрезают макет и в каком формате сохраняют вырезанные картинки (ну, например, иконки). Просто когда сам вырезал, какой бы формат (в котором сохранять) не пробовал - они получаются толще и менее чёткими.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jpeg 85 качество и png24 + если это именно иконки почитай что такое спрайты

Comment: Да, знаю, что это. Их только через спрайт делать? Просто мне нужно чтобы картинка была не background'ом блока, а частью, и находилась по середине..

Comment: Уже разобрался, всё нормально. Видимо когда-то так обрезал, но вот... Забыл.